# HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet: Error Log while running

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets, server

I have written a basic SpringMVC code, but when i was supposed to run the project i got some server error(I am using Tomcat 8.0 server),Below is my code

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SpringDemo</display-name>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  <!-- redirect to front controller -->
</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>                       <!-- maps incoming URL into DispatcherServlet -->
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"            
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
                                                                                  <!-- FrontController:it's job is to response back to client -->
    <bean id="HandlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />   <!-- HandlerMapping:Scans incoming URL pattern and maps into respective Controller -->

    <bean name="/welcome.html"
        class="com.pack1.hellocontroller.HelloController" />

      <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>               <!-- sends back responses to the client -->
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.pack1.hellocontroller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;  //AbstractController:basic controller class from springmvc

public class HelloController extends AbstractController{

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        ModelAndView modelandview = new ModelAndView("HelloPage");          //viewresolver name:HelloPage
        modelandview.addObject("msg", "hello, it's my first springmvc application");

        return modelandview;               //returns java object to the FrontController
    }
}
```

**HelloPage.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>SpringMVC</h1>
<h2>${msg}</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: If this is your first connection with spring, why you dont use spring-boot, more oriented to annotations and less configuration? would be easier to understand and faster to start develop :)

Comment: Okay thanks for the suggestion, i'll try out:)

Answer (score 0):

Change your **spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml** like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"            
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
                                                                                  <!-- FrontController:it's job is to response back to client -->
    <context:component-scan base-package = "com.pack1" />

    <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/" />
      <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Make sure your jsp files are into **WEB-INF** folder

Now in your controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HelloController{

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcome(){
        return new ModelAndView("HelloPage", "msg", "Hello Spring MVC Framework");
    }

}
```

Regards,

Comment: Why do you think `load-on-startup` is necessary? They already have a `ViewResolver` and they are using the Spring 2 Controller mechanism, without annotations. You haven't addressed their issue, only a potential workaround.

Comment: Yes, was my fault sorry.